# Where to Aggregate Using Microsoft Reporting Services?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I'm working on my first SSRS report and I haven't been able to find general guidelines as to how to create reports. Specifically, I would like to know what the general approach is when aggregate data is needed on a report. For example, let's say I need to show the following in my report:

Pancakes ---34 
Eggs----------56 
Bacon--------73

I have a several more rows like the above that need to show aggregate data. I'm currently grouping the whole row by type and then on each cell I'm showing a count as follows: [Count(Status)].

My report is already taking 45+ seconds to run. Is it generally preferable to do aggregation like this in the query? Or does this depend on the amount of data being returned? Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all SQL answers: *it depends*.

But generally do your aggregation in SQL. SQL server is much better at performing aggregation than the report layer. Also bringing back less rows will reduce your data transfer and the amount of data which SSRS needs to process. Usually you would only want to do the aggregation at the report layer if there are other constraints which make doing it in the SQL query impossible or if doing so will make the report more difficult to maintain in the future. (There's certainly something to be said for sacrificing a bit of performance in the name of maintainability.) One case would be when you need to display all of the data and returning two datasets is either too complicated or actually slows down the performance of the report.

As a side note, if your report is taking 45+ seconds to run then likely your SQL is not optimized very well or your report is doing a lot of complicated calculations. The more work you can put back on the SQL server the better your performance will be. SQL Server is made for crunching numbers and doing aggregations so certainly let it do what it does best when you can.

YMMV, so always do performance testing for different methods to see what works best.

Comment: Thank you for that very insightful response!